# Does the Poloniex minimum deposit amount apply to mining rewards?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, poloniex

I am setting up my mining pool and need to set a payment threshold.

The minimum deposit for ETH on Poloniex is 1 ETH. Does this apply to mining rewards?

Say (hypothetically) I set my threshold to 0.1 ETH. Would it be the case that I never get any deposits into my Poloniex wallet, or would it just be a case of waiting until 1 whole ETH had built up before it gets credited?